# UIView method called after drawRect

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Is there a UIView method that is called called after drawRect is completed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't. What would you need a method like that for?

If you absolutely need this, you can always subclass UIView and override drawRect message like this:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
   [super drawRect:rect];
   // do your stuff here
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I want to resize the contentSize of the superview based on what is drawn.

Comment: Can I use this method to prepare view properties before calling `[super drawRect:]`? For example to avoid multiple calculations per once drawing. Or classes with implemented `drawRect:` works differently and may be slowed down?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [`viewDidAppear:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidAppear:). Make sure to use an `UIViewController`.

Comment: The `UIView` equivalent is `-[UIView didMoveToSuperview]`